# Generate QR code image stream or bytes for Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, qr-code, zxing.net

I am struggling big time with generating QR barcodes as a `byte[]` or Stream (something that I can use on a XAML image source)

## ZXING.NET

I've tried with Zxing.Net but I find the documentation is not great.
In fact, when installing in the xamarin forms class library I am able to compile, but as soon as I add some code to write barcodes I get a compilation error saying that

```
Can not resolve reference: `zxing`, referenced by `MyXamarinFormsClassLibrary`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `zxing`, or remove the reference to `Sasw.AforoPass`.          0
```

Something funky is going on with that library.

And I'm doing a simple example such as:

```
var options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions
{
    DisableECI = true,
    CharacterSet = "UTF-8",
    Width = 250,
    Height = 250
};

var writer = new BarcodeWriter<Image>();
writer.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
writer.Options = options;

var result = writer.Write("foo");
MyImage.Source = result.Source;
```

## QRCoder

It's another nuget library. I've successfully used for dotnet core applications, but it does not seem to be compatible with Xamarin Forms (or Mono, or whatever). It says that the platform is not supported. Probably because it uses `System.Drawing.Common`?

## ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms

I've used this other library which underneath it uses ZXing.Net. What I don't like is that I don't know if there's any way to generate qr codes without relying on Xaml or the `ZXingBarcodeImageView`.

I managed to generate QR Codes that way as a workaround, but I hit another wall. See https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/issues/908 in which I describe the problems I have to embed the `ZXingBarcodeImageView` in a carousel inside a popup.

So basically I wanted to go back to the roots, and simply have a working example with the latest version of ZXing.Net (**or an alternative, if it exists**) that I am able to use in Xamarin Forms.

Most of the examples I find talk about `BarcodeWriter` but there is no such a class anymore. There is a generic one `BarcodeWriter<TUnknownType>`and a `BarcodeWriterGeneric` but as I said, I could not compile anything using `Zxing.Net` library and with through ZXing.Net.Mobile the images I generate are always empty.

Any help or "modern" code sample (ideally with an alternative) would be much appreciated

---

**UPDATE 1**
In other words, I'm looking to have in Xamarin Forms something similar to this code that I had using QrCoder library.

```
public class QrCodeService
        : IQrCodeService
    {
        public Stream GetQrCode(Guid id, string mimeType = "image/jpeg")
        {

            if (mimeType is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mimeType));
            }

            var qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
            var qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(id.ToString(), QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
            var qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData);
            var qrCodeImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);
            var myImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo(mimeType);
            var myEncoder = Encoder.Quality;
            var myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
            var myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 50L);
            myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            qrCodeImage.Save(stream, myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters);
            stream.Position = 0;
            return stream;
        }

        private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(string mimeType)
        {
            var encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
            foreach (var encoder in encoders)
            {
                if (encoder.MimeType == mimeType)
                {
                    return encoder;
                }
            }
            throw new KeyNotFoundException($"Encoder for {mimeType} not found");
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/iamlawrencev/QRCodeGenerator-Xamarin.Forms

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try following the sample. Although it uses the same library I was using that generated the platform not supported exception. But it looks promising the repo!

Comment: You can share your solution in the answer and mark it which will help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 2):

[QrCoder](https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder) library can do this, but instead of using as in the main page of the project:

```
QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode("The text which should be encoded.", QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData); // This point onwards is problematic
Bitmap qrCodeImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(20); // This will throw not supported exception
```

Switch the last 2 lines to:

```
var qrCode = new PngByteQRCode(qrCodeData);
byte[] imageByteArray = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);
```

You'll get byte array instead, but you can convert it into Stream or whatever you like afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The solution uses QrCoder library and it works fine for Xamarin Forms as follows.

```
private byte[] GetQrImageAsBytes()
{
   var randomText = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
   var qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
   var qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(randomText, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.L);
   var qRCode = new PngByteQRCode(qrCodeData);
   var qrCodeBytes = qRCode.GetGraphic(20);
   return qrCodeBytes;
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/sunnyatticsoftware/issue-xamarin-carousel-images/blob/master/App265/App265/App265/MainPage.xaml.cs) a working sample with this implementation